# Как отправлять формы из базы данных в телеграм каналы aiogram + sqlite3

Tags: python, база-данных, telegram-bot, aiogram, sqlite3

Я разрабатываю тг бота на aiogram, который должен отправлять формы из базы данных в телеграм каналы(sqlite3)

Но мне выводиться ошибка name 'ret' is not defined хотя переменную ret я объявил глобальной

форма скидываеться если кидать её самому пользователю, но не кидаеться в каналы телеграм (в каналах бот присутствует и он админ)

Извините за такой большой код, я просто джун и не понимаю что можно вырезать, но там не сложно разобраться

База данных:

```
import sqlite3 as sq
from create_bot import bot
from aiogram import types, Dispatcher
import logging
from handlers import admin

def sql_start():
    global base, cur
    base = sq.connect('pizza_cool.db')
    cur = base.cursor()
    if base:
        print('Data base connect OK!')
    base.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS menu(img TEXT, name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, description TEXT, size TEXT, color TEXT, price TEXT)')
    base.commit()

async def sql_add_command(state):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO menu VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', tuple(data.values()))
        base.commit()

async def sql_read(message):
    global ret
    for ret in cur.execute('SELECT * FROM menu').fetchall():
        pass
        # await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, ret[0], f'{ret[1]}\nОписание: {ret[2]}\nЦена: {ret[-1]}')

async def sql_read2():
    return cur.execute('SELECT * FROM menu').fetchall()

async def sql_delete_command(data):
    cur.execute('DELETE FROM menu WHERE name == ?', (data,))
    base.commit()
    # await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, ret[0], f'{ret[1]}\nОписание: {ret[2]}\nЦена: {ret[-1]}')
```

код админа:

```
from aiogram import types, Dispatcher
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from create_bot import dp, bot
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text
from data_base import sqlite_db
from KeyBoards import chat_case, button_case_admin
import logging
import sqlite3 as sq
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton, ReplyKeyboardRemove

async def make_changes_command(message: types.Message):
    global ID
    ID = message.from_user.id
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Что хотел?', reply_markup=button_case_admin) #reply_markup=admin_cb.button_case_admin
    logger.debug('the ansver is %r', message.text)

# @dp.message_handler(commands = 'load', state = None)
async def cm_start(message : types.Message):
    if message.from_user.id == ID:
        await FSMAdmin.photo.set()
        await message.reply('Ну ладно, Кидай фотки')

# @dp.message_handler(content_types = ['photo'], state=FSMAdmin.photo)
async def load_photo(message : types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.from_user.id == ID:
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            data['photo'] = message.photo[0].file_id
        await FSMAdmin.next()
        await message.reply('Название?')

# @dp.message_handler(state=FSMAdmin.name)
async def load_name(message : types.Message, state : FSMContext):
    if message.from_user.id == ID:
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            data['name'] = message.text
        await FSMAdmin.next()
        await message.reply('Введите описание')

async def load_description(message : types.Message, state : FSMContext):
    if message.from_user.id == ID:
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            data['description'] = message.text
        await FSMAdmin.next()
        await message.reply('Какие размеры у вас имеються')

# @dp.message_handler(state=FSMAdmin.description)
async def load_size(message : types.Message, state : FSMContext):
    if message.from_user.id == ID:
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            data['size'] = message.text
        await FSMAdmin.next()
        await message.reply('Какие цвета у вас имеються?')

async def load_color(message : types.Message, state : FSMContext):
    if message.from_user.id == ID:
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            data['color'] = message.text
        await FSMAdmin.next()
        await message.reply('Укажите цену')

# @dp.message_handler(state=FSMAdmin.price)
async def load_price(message : types.Message, state : FSMContext):
    if message.from_user.id == ID:
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            data['price'] = message.text
        await sqlite_db.sql_add_command(state)
        await state.finish()

async def test(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(CHANNEL_ID, 'dkdkdkdk')

def register_handler_admin(dp : Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(cm_start, commands = ['Load_product'], state = None)
    dp.register_message_handler(load_photo, content_types = ['photo'], state = FSMAdmin.photo)
    dp.register_message_handler(load_name, state = FSMAdmin.name)
    dp.register_message_handler(load_description, state = FSMAdmin.description)
    dp.register_message_handler(load_price, state = FSMAdmin.price)
    dp.register_message_handler(load_color, state = FSMAdmin.color)
    dp.register_message_handler(load_size, state = FSMAdmin.size)
    dp.register_message_handler(cancel_handler, state='*', commands = 'cancel')
    dp.register_message_handler(cancel_handler, Text(equals='cancel', ignore_case=True), state='*')
    dp.register_message_handler(make_changes_command, commands = ['moderator'], is_chat_admin=True)
    dp.register_message_handler(test, commands='test')
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Извините за такие объёмы кода, просто не понимаю что можно убрать

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибку по переменной выдаёт, потому как переменная, объявленная глобальной, при этом нигде не объявлена. Переменная в цикле for, временная, если можно так выразиться, она существует пока работает цикл.
Про сам цикл можно почитать здесь: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement

Объявлять переменную глобальной, имеет смысл если нужно эту самую переменную изменить, по итогу работы какой-либо функции. Например:

```
ret = 0

def count():
    global ret
    for i in range(1,8):
        ret += 1
    return ret
```

Что касаемо отправки сообщения (формы) в группу, а не конкретному пользователю, то нужно просто выбрать подходящий для этого метод.

Всё зависит от того, как нужно это реализовать.

```
await message.reply(# текс, значения из переменных и т.д.)
# это вариант ответа на само сообщение, с указанием сообщения на которое отвечаем
```

Или

```
await answer()
```

В параметрах отсылаемого сообщения можно выбрать всё что душе угодно, и "chat_id" в том числе.
Вся необходимая информация есть в документации
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Наконец то я закончу этого бота)